# Hibernate Query result cannot be cast to List<Subject>

Tags: java, hibernate, casting, hql

```
    Session s = ...;
    String query = "from pojo.Subject sub inner join sub.students stu group by "
      + "stu.FName having count(sub.subName) > 1";

    Query q = s.createQuery(query);
    List<Subject> list = q.list();
    for (Subject subj : list) {//error occurs here..
        System.out.println(subj.getSubName()+" - "+subj.getDay());

    }
```

It gives me an error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to pojo.Subject
    at hibernm.Application.main(Application.java:39)
```

I know that I can retrieve data by :

```
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Object get = list.get(i);
        System.out.println(get);

    }
```

But it doesn't seem like a proper way for me at all.
So I tried with introducing another 
list and iterating it :

```
    List<Subject> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final Object o : q.list()) {
        myList.add((Subject) o);//error occurs here..
    }
```

But it gives me the very same result.

So hope you guys get me clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: Add it to your question using the edit function not as a comment. And mark the line where the exception occured `Application.java:39`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are selecting not `Subject` but `inner joined` columnset, so it will not give you back `List<Subject>` instead a list of column arrays including columns of `Student` as well as `Student`, possibly a `List<Object[]>`

So in order to work your query result,you might do like(or try to inspect the query result by debugging):

```
Query query = session.createQuery(query);
List<Object[]> listResult = query.list();

for (Object[] aRow : listResult) {
    Subject subject = (Subject) aRow[0];
    Student student = (Student) aRow[1];
    //do your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to pojo.Subject
>      at hibernm.Application.main(Application.java:39)

This translates to: You cannot cast an `Array` of `Object` into a `Subject`.

If you check [Hibernate API docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list()) you wil find that

> ```
> public List list()
>         throws HibernateException
> ```
>
> Return the query results as a List. If the query contains 
>       *multiple results pre row*, the results are returned in an instance of Object[].

Which is exactly what happens in your case - you get **multiple results per row** - one `Subject` and one `Student` each because of the inner join.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I think what @Jan is saying is true, but since you only want the result from Subject, I think you can do something like this:

```
String query = "Select sub from pojo.Subject sub inner join sub.students stu group by "
      + "stu.FName having count(sub.subName) > 1";
```

And

```
Query q = s.createQuery(query, Subject.class);
List<Subject> list = q.getResultList();
```

Comment: It would be awesome if I could do so. But unfortunately there is no such a method accept `String` and `class type` both in `SharedSessionContract` interface . :)